# Twilio StatusCallback not working:

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest, twilio-api

So I'm building an app with twilio voice, and I've got all the phonecall stuff working. But I'm having a little trouble understanding which parameters my callback should have.

I've registered the URL as described in the docs:

```
                options.From = formatPhoneNumber(callout.callback_number);
                options.To = formatPhoneNumber(offer.employee_phone_number);
                options.Url = TwilioCallBotController.TwilioCalloutScriptURL;
                options.StatusCallback = TwilioCallBotController.StatusCallbackURL;
                options.StatusCallbackEvents = new []{"initiated", "ringing", "answered", "completed" };
                options.StatusCallbackMethod = "POST";
```

I've also made a callback method here, but I'm not having much luck finding out how the parameters are supposed to work with their API. I'm kindof at a loss as to what could be the reason behind this one not working:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult TwilioStatusCallback()
        {
            var twiml = new Twilio.TwiML.TwilioResponse();
            twiml.Say("This is a test");
            string CallSid = Request.Form["CallSid"];
            string CallStatus = Request.Form["CallStatus"];
            Debug.WriteLine("Status Callback Delivered");
            Shift_Offer shoffer = db.Shift_Offers.Where(s => s.twillio_sid == CallSid).ToList()[0];
            shoffer.status = CallStatus.ToString();// + DateTime.Now.ToString();
            return TwiML(twiml);
        }
```

Edit:
So it turns out that the API is very sensitive about the method signature (the call was previously throwing a method not found exception in a number of microsoft DLLs, including System.Web and System.Web.Mvc.

So I've actually gotten the software to call the method by using an empty method signature (no parameters).

However I'm still having trouble getting the parameters from the HTTPPOST

Edit: So upon further investigation I've managed to inspect the Request. The values I'm after exist in Request.Form["foo"], but they don't seem to be getting put into the two strings I have declared. I've removed the ["HttpPost"] attribute to try to troubleshoot the issue, but I'm really at a loss as to why I can see the values in the debugger, but they're not translating into memory.

```
public ActionResult TwilioStatusCallback()
{
    var twiml = new Twilio.TwiML.TwilioResponse();
    string sid = Request.Form["CallSid"];
    string status = Request.Form["CallStatus"];
    Shift_Offer shoffer = db.Shift_Offers.Where(s => s.twillio_sid == sid).ToList()[0];
    shoffer.status = status;// + DateTime.Now.ToString();
    return TwiML(twiml);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Last issue was that the database wasn't being saved.

Just added a db.SaveChanges() and we're good.